# Prove that $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{p_{1}},\sqrt{p_{2}},\ldots,\sqrt{p_{n}}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=2^{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots,p_{n}$
  be $n$
  primes,$\left(p_{i},p_{j}\right)=1$
  if $i\neq j$
 . Prove that $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{p_{1}},\sqrt{p_{2}},\ldots,\sqrt{p_{n}}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=2^{n}$

Help me some hints.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: See http://www.mathpuzzle.com/SumOfRoots.txt

Comment: You will find Bill Dubuque's [answer to this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of) very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this inductively.  The key is to show that $[Q(\sqrt{p}_1, \ldots \sqrt{p_{n+1}}) \colon \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{p_n})] = 2$.  The extension is obtained by adjoining a root of $x^2 - p_{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{p_n})$, so the degree can only be $1$ or $2$.  To show that it's $2$, you just need to prove that $x^2 - p_{n+1}$ doesn't have a root.  This calls for a tiny bit of number theory.

Comment: $x^2 - p_{n+1}$ doesn't have a root since it's irreducible.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 I agree, but you have to prove this: note that $x^2 - p_{n+1}$ could be reducible if there were any pairwise common divisors among $p_1, \ldots, p_{n+1}$.  This is why a little number theory is required.

Comment: Ehm... of course

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**-Prove that $S=\{\Pi_{i \in U}\sqrt{p_i}\ | U \subseteq \{1,2...,n\} \}$ is a linearly independent set in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{p_{1}},\sqrt{p_{2}},\ldots,\sqrt{p_{n}}]$ and that every element in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{p_{1}},\sqrt{p_{2}},\ldots,\sqrt{p_{n}}]$ is a linear combination (over $\Bbb Q$) of elements in $S$.