# Characterizing $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})/\mathbb{Q})$ for $p_i$ primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, extension-field

For what $n$ is
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})/\mathbb{Q})
$$
known, where the $p_i$ are primes?

By Kummer theory, I think that 
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n}))/\mathbb{Q})\simeq A/(\mathbb{Q}^\times)^2
$$
where $A$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ generated by $(\mathbb{Q}^\times)^n$ and the $p_i$. But it's not clear to me what $A/(\mathbb{Q}^\times)^n$ is. Intuitively, it should probably be $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, since we should have an automorphism permuting $\pm\sqrt{p_i}$ for any choice of indices $i$, and those are the only possible ways to permute the roots. It is somehow obvious that 
$$
A/(\mathbb{Q}^\times)^2\simeq(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n
$$
if one is thinking just in terms of groups?

Comment: Hint: Induct on the number of primes.

Comment: You may find of interest the papers of Mordell and Siegel cited in my [answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242)