# Is $\phi: a + b \sqrt{2} \rightarrow a + b\sqrt{3}$ a $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ field isomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory

Is $\phi: a + b \sqrt{2} \rightarrow a + b\sqrt{3}$ a $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ field isomorphism?

Some book I'm reading says so.

But I'm a bit lost: for field isomorphism, it's required that $\phi(uv) = \phi(u) \phi(v)$.

Choosing $u = v = a + b \sqrt{2}$, we have

$$LHS = \phi((a + b \sqrt{2})(a+b\sqrt{2})) = \phi((a^2 + 2 b^2) + 2 ab \sqrt{2}) = (a^2 + 2b^2) + 2ab \sqrt{3}$$

$$RHS = \phi(a + b\sqrt{2}) \phi(a + b\sqrt{2}) = (a + b\sqrt{3})(a + b\sqrt{3}) = (a^2 + 3b^2) + 2ab \sqrt{3} $$

Seems they don't tally?

Comment: The question is : are you sure that they are isomorphic? because they are not isomorphic maybe this is what you need to prove.

Comment: @user46944 i don't get your point...

Comment: What is the *exact* wording in that book.  (Because what you said, as we have seen in the comments, is false.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two fields are not isomorphic: assume the existence of an isomorphisme $\varphi$ and let $\varphi(\sqrt{2})=a+\sqrt3b$, because $\sqrt{2}×\sqrt{2}=1+1$. Hence $\varphi(\sqrt2)^2=\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)=2$. Hence $(a+\sqrt{3}b)^2=2$, so :
$$a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt{3}=2+0\sqrt3 $$

and using the uniqueness of the writing $a+b\sqrt{3}$ we conclude that $ab=0$ and $a^2+3b^2=2$ hence either $2$ or $\frac{2}{3}$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is it ok now or I need to prove that $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Elaqqad Maybe you should prove the associativity of addition in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ as you use it. ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: @Steven [This Lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/777171/242) implies $\,\sqrt{2}\not\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})\,$ by reducing it to the equivalent statement that $\,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6\not\in\Bbb Q,\,$ i.e. all are all irrational.

Comment: @Elaqqad This version looks really solid to me.

Answer (score 3):

You need no tricky computation. If $\phi$ is an ring homomorphism, then $\phi(2)=2$, but
$$
\phi(0+1\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{3}
$$
and
$$
2=\phi(2)=\phi(\sqrt{2})^2=3
$$

Comment: how can you prove that $\phi(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 3$ because i don't see any justification for your second equality

Comment: @Elaqqad By definition of $\varphi$: $\varphi(a+b\sqrt{2})=a+b\sqrt{3}$, take $a=0$, $b=1$.

Comment: @edred The definition of a field isoùorphism is the following: $$\phi(uv)=\phi(u)\phi(v)\\ \phi(u+v)=\phi(u)+\phi(v)\\ \phi(0)=0;\phi(1)=1 $$ but you can justify your equality because the fields are of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ still the question is that how this justification works?

Comment: @Elaqqad I took the definition from your question. Now, $\varphi(2)=2$ by definition and $\varphi(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ by definition. However, $2=(\sqrt{2})^2$, but $2=\varphi(2)=\varphi((\sqrt(2))^2)$, but $\varphi(\sqrt{2})^2=(\sqrt{3})^2=3$. So this $\varphi$ is surely not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: ok you're right I did not read the question very well (it's not mine) because in my answer I proved that there is no isomorphism from the given fields, but the question asks if the given application is an isomorphism

Comment: @Elaqqad Sorry for having thought you were the OP; yes, your answer is more general.