# Why doesn't there exist a ring homomorphism between these two rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Why doesn't there exist a ring homomorphism between $\mathbf{Q}[x]/(x^2-2) $ and $\mathbf{Q}[x]/(x^2 -3) $?

I see both rings are in fact fields as the polynomials are irreducible, further I know for $T$ to be a ring homomorphism then

$T(1)=1$

$T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$

$T(xy)=T(x)T(y)$

I tried proving by contradiction but wasn't really sure how to start

Comment: To finish Robert's answer it suffices to show that $\,\sqrt{2}\not\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}),\,$ which follows by [this Lemma,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/777171/242) which reduces it to $\,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\,$ are all irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first ring $2$ has a square root (namely, the class of $x$ modulo $x^2 -2$), and in the second it has not square-root (check it). As any mophism of ring from the first to the second ring would send a square root of $2$ to a square of $2$, no such morphism exists.

Comment: Why would any mophism of ring from the first to the second ring would send a square root of 2 to a square of 2?

Comment: Take $f$ such a morphism. Note $a$ the class of $x$. Then $2 = f(2) = f(a^2) = f(a)f(a) = (f(a))^2$. (Note that for any ring morphism you have $f(n)=n\cdot 1$ when $n\in\mathbf{Z}$.)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by class? and why is 2=f(2)? or have we taken such an f that 2=f(2)

Comment: You have a "canonical" morphism $\mathbf{Q}[x]\to \mathbf{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$, and the class of an element $P\in \mathbf{Q}[x]$ is by definition the image of $P$ by this morphism. Are you familiar with quotients of a ring by an ideal of the ring ?

Comment: I know that quotients of a ring by an ideal of the ring also forms a ring and that there's a homomorphism between a ring and this quotient

Comment: Then you know everything you need. Do you understand my answer now ?

Comment: Yeah I see it now, thanks for helping me once again :-)

Comment: @learnmore Read my answer and my first comment to it.

Comment: @learnmore Because the square of $\sqrt{3}$ is $3$ and not $2$. Read my answer and my first comment to it.

Comment: To finish this answer see my comment on the question.

Comment: @TheProblem it is customary to assume that f(1)=1 for a ring homomorphism between rings with identity. under this assumption we can state that f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=1+1=2. Otherwise, it is not true. Between any two rings, there is always a homomorphism, namely the trivial one. in that case f(2)=0