# Showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For $a, b\in\mathbb{Q}$ I have to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$.

Unfortunately I dont even know where to start. We never used these brackets $(-)$ before, so I dont know how these sets are actually defined.

I would be grateful for the definitions (:D) and any kind of help or advice! Thank you!

Comment: How is $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ defined?

Comment: I dont know that either, all we have dealt with so far is for example $\mathbb{Q}[a]$. We have never used this round brackets

Comment: Whatever reference you are using will define a [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension); that's what the notation refers to.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not understand that "brackets" were ( and ) (thought it was -). So, how is $\Bbb{Q}[a]$ defined?

Comment: @manooooh We defined it as $\mathbb{Q}[a]=\{ x+ya | x,y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: I added a [dupe link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777141/how-to-convert-bbb-q-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-to-bbb-q-alpha) which explains the key idea more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: ${1\over{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}}$ $={{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}\over {a-b}}$ implies that $\sqrt a-\sqrt b\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$.

Comment: Warning: Not valid if $a = b$.

Comment: Ok, for $a\neq b$ I got that $\sqrt{a} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$ and then $\sqrt{b} = (\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})-\sqrt{a}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$. That means $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Answer (score 0):

If $a=b$ it's obvious.

Now,let $a\neq b$.

$$\sqrt{ab}=\frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2-a-b}{2}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}).$$
Thus, $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})\sqrt{ab}=a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}=a(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})+(b-a)\sqrt{a}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}).$$
Can you end it now?