# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Let $a$ and $b$ be rational numbers. Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b})$.

I think this question might have been asked before, but Google and the stackexchange search don't show anything.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260881/showing-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb?noredirect=1&lq=1) and several more (I know, even searching requires some practice).

Comment: Adapt https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3832301/589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $\Bbb Q(\sqrt a+\sqrt b) \subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt a, \sqrt,b)$ is clear.

Conversely, $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=a-b$ and so $\sqrt a -\sqrt b=(a-b)/(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$.

Thus $\sqrt a-\sqrt b\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$ and hence $(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)+(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = 2\sqrt a$ in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$, i.e., $\sqrt a\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)$. Similarly, $\sqrt b\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)$. Equality follows.