# How to get this equation solved?

Tags: prime-numbers

I came across this equation

$$\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5$$

And you have to find the value of '$a$' and '$b$' when both of them are primes. The solution was $a=7, b=5$.

Now, my question is, can't there be any other primes?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of

Comment: The current question is very much not a duplicate of the older question. That one is far more general, and the proof uses techniques that are likely well beyond the level at which the current question is to be attacked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Square both sides and we get $a+b-2\sqrt{ab}=12-2\sqrt{35}$. Hence, 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
a+b=12\\
ab=35
\end{array}\right.$$
Solve for $a,b$, and we have $a=7,b=5$ or $a=5,b=7$. Of course only the first one is correct.

Comment: Why can these equations to write?  I think its true the time, chose the numbers from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$.