# Sum of square root of non perfect square positive integers is always irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Let $S$ be a set of positive integers such that no element of $S$ is a perfect square. Is it true that $\sum_{s_i \in S} \sqrt{s_i}$ is always irrational?

**Motivation.** Suppose the length of the circumference of a polygon whose nodes are located on lattice points is an integer. I'm trying to figure out whether this implies that the lengths of all its sides must be integers as well.

Edit: This is a slightly more general question than [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of) (in particular, primes versus non-squares), but appears to be answered in the same way.

Comment: See https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/

Comment: The source material link in the above blog is broken.  See p. 87 of http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf

Comment: How would the radicals cancel out otherwise, if all terms are positive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The square roots of different primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of)

Comment: @Irvan: But in your problem statement, $S$ is a collection of positive integers? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @Gary sorry, I thought you were talking about how vadim123's link answers this question.

Comment: @Irvan: No problem, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes"; see [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf) (page 87)