# Show that $\sqrt{3}$ is not an element of the $\text{span} (1, \sqrt{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra

So we have the following given to us this weekend just on a handout:

Considering $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$, show that $\sqrt 3$ is not an element of the span of $(1, \sqrt 2)$.  His hint was to assume $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 2$ are not elements of $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 3$ is not in the span of $\sqrt 2$.

Assuming that he will want something short and sweet since on his handout, and I know the span means that I have to show that no linear combination of 1 and $\sqrt 2$ will ever equal $\sqrt 3$.  Yet for some reason I seem to be going in circles with this problem.  Do I need to even worrying about $\mathbb Q$ or not.  Anybody with hints or ideas?

Comment: "*I don't know why its not letting type the square root symbols today*" See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: Related general case, but not the same  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of

Answer (score 10):

Suppose we could find some $a,b$ in the rationals with 
$$
a+b\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{3}
$$
If $a=0$, then we have that 
$$
b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
Put $b=p/q$ is into lowest terms and mimic the proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, namely 
$$
2p^2=3q^2
$$ 
which means $p$ is divisible by $3$ and $q$ by $2$, and thus $p^2$ is divisible by $9$ and $q^2$ by $4$, thus $q$ is divisible by $3$ and $p$ by $2$ s well, contradicting our putting the fraction in lowest terms, since both $gcd(p,q)\geq 6$.

If b is zero, then we have that $\sqrt{3}$ is rational.

So, this then means that 
$$
a^2+2ab\sqrt{2}+2b^2=3\implies\sqrt{2}=\frac{3-2b^2-a^2}{2ab}
$$
a contradiction of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.