# Prove linear independence of roots of square-free numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ using induction

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove that this system $\{1,\sqrt{m_1},\sqrt{m_2},...,\sqrt{m_n}\}$, where all $m_i$ are different square-free  natural numbers, is linear independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. My teacher has asked me to prove this using induction.

1. BASE CASE: $a_11+a_2\sqrt{m_1}$ linear independent. It's obviously.
2. STEP CASE: Supouse $\sum\limits_i^{n-1}a_i\sqrt{m_i}\neq0$ for any $a_i\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Now I need to show that $\sum\limits_i^{n}a_i\sqrt{m_i}\neq0$. Everything I can do next is to rewrite it like this(since $a_n\neq0$): $\sqrt{m_n}=\sum\limits_i^{n-1}b_i\sqrt{m_i}$.

But I can't make any contradiction.

EDIT: 
$m_i\gt1, \forall i$

Comment: This follows from the answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of/1803809). It works for different squarefree integers, not necessarily primes. For the induction, see the reference "Besicovitch".

Comment: I would show by induction on k that the field Q(sqrt(P1), .., sqrt(pk) ) has dimension 2^k over Q. How to do it? Hint: it is enough to show that sqrt(p_k) does not belong to Q(P1,..,pk-1). Then, if you have sqrt(M1), .. sqrt(MN) distinct , this belongs to Q( sqrt(primes)). And think why this forces them to be linearly independent.

Comment: @AndreaMarino ok, $\{1,\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_k}\}$ will be basis of that field. And our $\sqrt{m_1}...$ wil be multiplication of basis vectors?

Comment: No, they won't be a basis over Q. Think about Q(sqrt(2), sqrt(3) ). What is a basis? Generally if you have a basis of L over F, and a basis of F over k, how can you make a basis of L over K? Use inductively this reasoning to build up a basis of Q(sqrt(primes))

Comment: @AndreaMarino basis in Q(sqrt2, sqrt3) will be {1, sqrt2, sqrt3, sqrt6)?

Comment: @AndreaMarino and maybe a soon as we know all primes which are in our m_i we can build Q(sqrt2...) and made change of basis? It will be subspace as our m_i are square-free?

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's the main problem. How to show that there is no linear combination for sqrt2(p_n)? It looks like my original question