# If $k_1, \ldots, k_n$ are non-square, pairwise coprime, then $\sqrt {k_n} \not \in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt {k_1}, \ldots, \sqrt {k_{n-1}})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Seems intuitive. Like the fact that $\sqrt 3 \not \in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt 2)$. But how to approach actually proving it? The proof of this fact doesn't seem to generalize well.

Comment: Duplicate of [The square roots of different primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of)   (the general proof there works here and more generally)