# $\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{y} + 3\sqrt{z} + 4\sqrt{t}\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $x, y, z, t\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{y} + 3\sqrt{z} + 4\sqrt{t}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then show that $\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}, \sqrt{z}, \sqrt{t} \in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You forgot the initial \$ and the \ before sqrt in the title. Did you mean $4\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: Why did you write $3\sqrt z+4\cdot\sqrt z$ instead of $7\sqrt z$?

Comment: I guess the last $\sqrt z$ is $\sqrt t$ instead.

Comment: Is there a mutiplication with dot and an other without?

Comment: A closely related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of) (from back in the days when an answer by @BillDubuque could attract over 100 votes.

Answer (score 0):

if $sqrt(x), sqrt(y), sqrt(z), sqrt(t)$ are NOT elements of Q. Then $sqrt(x) + 2sqrt(y) + 3sqrt(z) + 4sqrt(t)$ is NOT an element of Q. If the elements are not elements of Q then they are elements of R - Q. You need to prove R - Q is closed under addition and multiplication.