# Sums of square roots

Tags: summation, radicals

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m$ be two (finite) lists of positive integers such that no $a_i$ or $b_j$ is a perfect square ($m$ may or may not be the same as $n$). Can the following equality hold?

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{a_i} \stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{j = 1}^m \sqrt{b_j}.$$

I just came up with this question, so I don't know what sort of techniques may be used to dis/prove this, or if there are any trivial solutions that can be excluded (other than $a_i = b_i$ up to re-indexing).

Edit: Suppose also that all $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s are required to be relatively prime.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include square roots. Thanks!

Comment: What about$$\sqrt{12}=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Hmm. Maybe those are the trivial cases that I was thinking of. What if all $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s are required to be relatively prime?

Comment: @taninamdar Or square free. I think that's a more reasonable and interesting requirement.

Comment: @Arthur could you provide an answer with that requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure. In that case it does sound to me like only trivially equal sums should be equal, but I don't really know.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of