# Is any combination of roots (eg, $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$) a unique number?

Tags: roots

Every non negative real number has a unique non negative root, called the principle square root. Does this mean that any combination of roots added will also produce a unique value?

For example,
$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} = 1.414213562373095\ldots + 1.732050807568877\ldots = 3.146264369941972\ldots$$
Is this resulting value as unique as each of the two principle square roots that were added?

Is there a way to prove this uniqueness mathematically or logically without producing a huge table of all possible combinations to check against each other?

Comment: $\sqrt2+\sqrt 3$ is the sum of the two aforementioned numbers, therefore it is that specific real number.

Comment: No: $\sqrt 1+\sqrt{16}=\sqrt 4+\sqrt 9$

Comment: @Andrei Either you've misunderstood the question or I have.

Comment: If $a$ is uniquely-defined, and if $b$ is uniquely-defined, then $a+b$ is uniquely-defined.

Comment: It’s really hard to know what you’re asking here.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking about minimal polynomials or something along those lines?  $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ has the minimal polynomial $x^4-10x^2+1$ and that quartic has two positive roots.

Comment: Writing $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ expresses an unambiguous sum of unambiguous values. However, writing $x+y$, and all I know is that $x^2=2$ and $y^2=3$, expresses an ambiguous sum that has no inherent value ... although I *can* say that there are only four values attainable by the expression (namely, $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, $\sqrt2-\sqrt3$, $-\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, and $-\sqrt2-\sqrt3$).

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are assuming the existence and uniqueness of roots of non-negative real numbers (in fact, this is not hard to prove rigorously), Yes. Because  $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is the principle square root of $5+\sqrt{24}.$