# Trying to find a basis

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some issues to prove that a basis for K over F is $\prod_{i\in S}{\sqrt{d_i}}$. I know that the basis contains $2^k$ elements but I don't know how to move on.
I hope for some help!

[image]

Comment: There is a nice hint you can use there. Have you tried following that?

Comment: Duplicate of the duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837191/induction-on-k-algebra?noredirect=1#comment7915344_3837191

Comment: @sumi: you have already a link to answers in your previous post. There is no need to answer the same question twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Induction on k algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837191/induction-on-k-algebra)

Comment: Hi GreginGre! The reason I ask the same question twice is because I didn't understand the link you gave me and because that post was old I made a new one because I don't think that anyone would reply because it hasn't been active for a long time. :)

Comment: Hi Arthur! Thank you for your answer. Isn't the hint for the first part of the question were we are trying to prove that $[K:F]=2^k$ or can it be used for the second part too?