# Linear independence of square root of primes without abstract algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers, roots, rational-numbers

I recently found a linear algebra question from the very beginning of my first semester. Without any knowledge of abstract algebra, we were supposed to prove that if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, the numbers $1$, $\sqrt{p}$ and $\sqrt{q}$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent. I could not solve it back then and still can't now.

I really want to do it the brute force way without any background knowledge (maybe except $\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q} \notin \mathbb{Q}$), i.e. prove that if
$$
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2\sqrt{p}+\lambda_3 \sqrt{q}= 0
$$
for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.

I tried to move $\lambda_3 \sqrt{q}$ to the RHS and square both sides, but without much success.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30687/81360) is related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $\lambda_1$ to the other side, then square, which gives you that $\lambda_2\lambda_3\sqrt{pq}$ is rational. Hence one of $\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ is zero.