# Producing infinite family of transcendental numbers

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Weierstrass proved the result [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem] that if $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ are reals linearly independent over the rationals, then $e^{a_1}, \cdots, e^{a_n}$ are algebraically independent.

I would like to know if the result holds for infinitely many numbers. Explicitely, if $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots \}$ is an infinite family of real numbers such that every finite subset is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, then is it true that every finite subset of $\{ e^{a_1}, e^{a_2}, \cdots \}$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$?

I'd be happy to know any other result in that spirit.

---

Edit: Can one explicitly write an infinite family of real numbers linearly independent over the rationals?

(Sorry, this was the question I had originally in mind. Thanks anon for pointing that out).

Comment: Yes it is true, and it requires no more than LW itself and an understanding of logical implication. Doesn't look to me like the title relates to the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Gamma$ is a finite subset of $\{e^{a_1},e^{a_2}\cdots\}$, then $\Lambda=\{\log\gamma : \gamma\in\Gamma\}$ is a finite subset of $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$. The former is thus linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ by hypothesis, and by the LW theorem you cite this implies that $\{e^{\lambda}:\lambda\in\Lambda\}=\Gamma$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Does this answer your question?

---

*Update in response to OPs edit*: Yes, one can explicitly construct an example. Via [Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6250/11763):

$$\rm \Lambda=\{\, \log p: ~ p ~~ prime \,\} $$

is an example of an infinite set linearly independent over the rationals. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is key to understanding why this is independent. However, the $\Gamma$ associated to this $\Lambda$ (defined as before), i.e. the primes, are not even linearly independent, let alone algebraically, over the rationals. Is your question actually for an explicit $\mathbb{Q}$-lin. ind. $\Lambda$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-alg. ind. $\Gamma$?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't frame the question correctly. Edited the question now.

Comment: @Abhishek: I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes I want to see explicitly transcendental numbers. But again the question seems ill-posed. I will ask another question and choose your answer. Thanks.