# Infinitely many transcendental numbers over Q

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

My [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125741/producing-infinite-family-of-transcendental-numbers) was not well-framed so I will ask again:

Can you explicitly produce an infinite set of real numbers which is algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Let $S$ be any infinite set of algebraic real numbers linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example $\{\sqrt p : p \text{ is prime}\}$. (A maximal such set is a basis for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.)
Then $\{e^s : s \in S\}$ is algebraically independent.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-ration discusses the assertion made above about square roots of primes.

Comment: What if $S=\left\{\ln(2),\ln(3),\ln(5),\ldots\right\}$? The theorem requires $S$ to contain algebraic numbers, not any real numbers linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Bruno: also, to apply Lindemann-Weierstrass $S$ needs to consist of algebraic numbers.

Comment: Haha! Yes, absolutely. Thank you both. I knew that!

Comment: We can certainly produce a (necessarily uncountable) transcendence base for the reals. But to apply Lindemann-Weierstrass, we need the elements of $S$ to be algebraic.

Comment: My brain malfunctions in mysterious way - I used the theorem correctly, all while making this surprising claim... hmm!

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, this answers my question. $\sqrt p$ is such a set.