# $\log$ transform of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, prime-factorization

Taking the canonical form of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in the form:
$$n=\prod_{j=1}^\infty p^{m_j}_j \qquad ;m_j\in \Bbb N_0$$
Does anybody know about a $\log n$ transform of this?

Note: also reference to other works are welcome

Comment: What do you mean by a "$\log n$ transform" of the theorem? There is an internal direct sum decomposition of additive groups $\sum_{n\ge1}(\log n){\bf Z}=\bigoplus_p (\log p){\bf Z}$, if that's at all relevant.

Comment: What about it? What is it that you want to know that you don't already know?

Comment: I have never seen somewhere this form, although it seems so trivial. I was just wondering whether someone knows about this form elsewhere.

Comment: There is an answer on MSE somewhere (of Bill D) that proves $\{\log p\}$ are independent over the rationals using FToA. Otherwise I don't see any *point* in a text mentioning this form.

Comment: wasnt that post on the squares "The square roots of the primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals"?

Comment: No, it was [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb/6250#6250).

Comment: This is great Help, anon. Many thanks.

Comment: @anon Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I converted my comments into an answer two hours before your comment asking me to; is yours a boilerplate comment? At any rate, thanks for the links.

Comment: @anon Sorry then. I don't know why I didn't see it, maybe a bug, or I'm just blind. My comment is from the "list of comment templates" in meta. It was made by Lord_Farin and myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't clarify what "$\log$ transform" of FTA would look like. A trivial reformulation of FTA is that the log of any positive natural can be written uniquely as a $\bf N$-linear combination of logs of primes, but there is little aesthetic appeal in this formulation. Another algebraic version is this:

$$\log\left({\bf Q}^\times_{>0}\right)=\bigoplus_p (\log p){\bf Z}.$$

One application of this log perspective though is in exhibiting an infinite $\bf Q$-linearly independent set of real numbers, thereby proving that $\bf R$ is an infinite-dimensional $\bf Q$-vector space via arithmetic.

Comment: excellent. thanks. Do you have a reference for the latter possibly where I could read further?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi What latter possibility are you referring to? The direct sum isomorphism in the middle of this answer should be a basic exercise if you know abelian group theory and requires no reference outside of such. Using logs to show $\bf R$ is an infinite-dimensional $\bf Q$-vector space is also a pretty basic exercise, and I already linked to a reference in the comments.