# Find dimension of the intriguing vector space

Tags: integration, vector-spaces, proof-verification, vector-analysis, solution-verification

We are given vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb R$ of two variables with powers not higher than 2013.
Let's consider subspace $V$ which contains such polynomials $f$, so following holds for them:
$$\oint_{C} f(x,y)ds =0$$
Where $C = \{x^2+y^2 = R^2\}$.
Task is to find dim $V$.

First I must note that I felt undereducated for that problem when I first approached it, so I went through some books and materials and came up with solution.
**Solution**
I moved to polar coords and with use of the following formula I was able to write the required equation
[image: formula]
$$R\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k_1=0; k_2=0}^{2013}{a_{k_1 k_2}R^{k_1k_2}cos^{k_1}t \cdot sin^{k_2} t\space dt} = 0$$
By the way, I have doubts that this formula applies there. But if it is, 
$$cos^{p}(0)=cos^p(0);\space sin^{p}(2\pi)=sin^p(2\pi)$$
Hence, it's a trivial subspace and any polynomial fits.
Than, power spans from $0$ to $2013$ for both variables and basis should have all of them, than $dim V = 2013^2$
I have doubts about it's correctness, but my main concern is understanding. So I would appreciate hints and corrections.

Comment: Where did you get it, seems interesting. And, what is $C$ here? Unit circle?

Comment: @PA6OTA Sorry, I forgot $C$ definition. Yes, it's circle with radius R. Already made a fix in question. This task is from  Yandex school of data analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sketch:

- Let $X$ be the vector space of all polynomials with powers up to 2013.  Verify that $X$ has dimension $2014^2$ (remember to count the 0 power).
- Let $T : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map $Tf = \oint_C f$.  Verify that $T$ is linear and surjective (i.e. its range is all of $\mathbb{R}$).  (For surjectivity, it suffices to find a single $f$ such that $Tf \ne 0$).
- Observe that $V$ is the kernel (null space) of $T$.
- Recall the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: That's brilliant. Would you take a look at what I've got: $rk(T) + null(T) = dim(X)$. $dim(X)$ as you said, is $2014^2$ and rank of mapping $T$ is what I have trouble with. I found myself thinking about that as hard as I can for more than an hour. But probably I'm not deep enough in the set theory now. So I would appreciate pointer about calculating $rk(T)$. While thinking, I thought of another way - find $dim(V)$ directly - it's all possible polynomials with constraint: "there could not be an element having even powers for x and y both". But your way is of more beauty)

Comment: The rank is easier than you think. What's the definition of the rank of a linear transformation? As for your other characterization, I don't think it works: a polynomial of the form $x^2 y^2 +c$ will integrate to 0 for the right choice of the constant c.

Comment: For linear transformation rank is amount of linearly independent rows/cols. But since $T$ is mapping polynomials to numbers, I honestly fail to see it as linear transform... Concerning that another way -  yes, I agree with your objection.

Comment: Hint: the real numbers are a vector space of dimension 1.

Comment: $T: X \to \mathbb{R}$. $T(x) = Ax$ So we could consider element of X as column of coefficients $a_{ij}$, and A as row of according length. Then, it's clear that $rk(A)=1$. Also I find another definition of the rank of linear mapping: $rk(T)=dim(Im(T))$. Image of T would be $\mathbb{R}$, so according to your suggestion, this also gives $rk(T)=1$. Than $dim(V)=null(T)=2014^2-1$. But I still have doubts, though. We state that $dim(\mathbb{R})=1$. That holds when R is vector space over which field? I found proofs for space R over Q dim(R) is infinite. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244

Comment: Also, It seems slightly counter-intuitive, that answer not depend on actual integral, so it looks to me that we would have the same answer for another $C$? Is that correct? Nate, thanks for your explanations and patience, by the way:)

Comment: @wf34: you've got it! Yes, I'm assuming we're working over R; that's the most reasonable interpretation of this question. Over Q, yes, everything in sight would have infinite dimension. And yes, the answer would be the same for almost any other integral.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the dimension is certainly not $2013*2013$. For example, even-powered polynomials $x^{2n} y^{2m}$ certainly do not integrate to 0.

Hint: what do you know about $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^p\!\theta \cos^q\!\theta \, d\theta$?

Hint2: apply integration by parts twice to reduce $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^p\!\theta \cos^q\!\theta \, d\theta$ to $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{p-2}\!\theta \cos^{q+2}\!\theta \, d\theta$

Comment: Yep, I agree with that. I'll look into it and make an edit to question soon.

Comment: Probably not enough hint for me:( I don't know nothing specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

The given integral equation imposes a single linear condition. You just need to check that the relation is not trivial by finding a polynomial whose integral is nonzero.