# Why do we call a vector space in terms of vector space over some field?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am getting a bit confused with the terminology here. I understand that a field means some set of scalars like real numbers but why do we need a field for a vector space? Are not the numerical values used to define a vector are inherent properties of the vector space? Why do we term it like "vector space over real field"? If not numbers, what are the other fields possible for a vector space because you obviously numbers to define the value of magnitude and direction of the vectors?

Comment: Your title is somewhat confused: one does not define a vector space in terms of _a vector space_ over some field (which would be kind of circular); instead we define vector spaces while referring to some field that was fixed beforehand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775822/what-are-the-axioms-that-differentiate-a-complex-field-from-a-real-field/2775857?noredirect=1#comment5725660_2775857

Answer (score 14):

A vector space is defined as a quadruple $(V,K,+,\cdot)$ where $V$ is a set whose elements are called ''vectors'' , $K$ is a field, $+\colon V\times V \rightarrow V$ and $\cdot\colon K\times V \rightarrow V$ are operations that satisfy a suitable set of axioms (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)).

For the same set $V$ we can define different vector spaces changing the field $F$ and the difference can be dramatic.

The simpler case is for $V=\mathbb{R}$. If we take $K=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual addition and multiplication, we have a vector space of dimension $1$, but if we take $K=\mathbb{Q}$ we have a vector space that has a uncountable basis so its dimension is infinite ([Is there a quick proof as to why the vector space of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb)).

Another, less dramatic, example, is if $V=\mathbb{C}^n$: if we choose $K= \mathbb{C}$ than we have a vector space (with the usual operations) over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$, if we choose $K= \mathbb{R}$ we can obtain a space of dimension $2n$.

Again, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ the change is more relevant and we have a space of infinite (not countable) dimension.

Comment: @AdityaKumarGupta You seem to think that vectors can always be represented by tuples of scalars. The example here ($\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$) shows that this is not true.

Answer (score 4):

First you cannot define magnitude and direction for all vector spaces: these notions correspond to so-called *normed and/or *inner product* vector spaces*.

Next one has very naturally to consider vector spaces over $\mathbf C$, even in problems concerning real spaces. I'll mention Fourier series, or second order linear differential equations.

In arithmetic, one has to consider vector spaces over $\mathbf Q$ or algebraic number fields or $p$-adic numbers.

I once heard a well-known mathematician say cryptography, a domain closely related to arithmetic, is but the theory of finite-dimensional vector spaces over finite fields.

Answer (score 2):

> Are not the numerical values used to define a vector are inherent properties of the vector space?

Yes, they are. If you use other numerical values (like complex numbers, or $\mathbb F_2$), you get another vector space (for example $\mathbb F_2^3$ instead of $\mathbb R^3$). However you can also get a different vector spaces using the same field (for example, $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$). Now it turns out that vector spaces over the same field are in some sense compatible with each other, in a way that vector spaces over different fields generally are not. For example, it's no problem to define a linear function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$. However there are no linear functions $f:\mathbb F_2^2\to\mathbb R^2$. Therefore it makes sense to always explicitly say on which field the vector space is based.

Comment: Between vector space over unrelated fields, one cannot even _define_ the notion of linear map, since the definition requires the same scalars to be used in both spaces (more precisely, the linear map must commute with any scalar multiplication _applied in both spaces_).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You're right; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not all vector fields have "magnitutes". In order to have a magnitude of a vector, you need to have a norm defined on the vector space, and typically, only vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ have norms defined on them.

We have to say "vector space over real field" because we need to be careful about what we are doing at all times. For example, $[1,0,0]$ is an element of both $\mathbb R^3$ which is a vector space over $\mathbb R$, and an element of $\mathbb C^3$ which is a vector space over $\mathbb C$.

Furthermore, the fact that $\mathbb C$ is itself a vector space over $\mathbb R$ means that any vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C$ can also be seen as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, but of a different dimension.

You can also have vector spaces over other fields, like $\mathbb Z_p$ where $p$ is prime, and not define any norm there.