# If $x^3$ is a square, is $x$ a square?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Very simple question here, which I feel like I should be able to answer but am struggling with. Let $k$ be a finite field, and let $x\in k^\times$. Is it true that
$$x^3\in\left(k^\times\right)^2 \Longleftrightarrow x\in\left(k^\times\right)^2?$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$x=x^3/x^2$, so if $x^3=a^2$ then $x=(a/x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use proof by contradiction to show that $x$ is square, too. 
We can write $x$ into its prime factors: 
$$x = a_1^{p_1} \times ... \times a_n^{p_n}$$. 
Let us assume that the conclusion is false i.e. $x$ is not square. Then at least one of the factors has an odd power: 
$$p_j = 2k+1 \hspace{0.5in} j = 1,...,n$$. 
In $x^3$ this power will be $6k+3$ which is $3(2k+1)$ (which is the product of two odd numbers and thus is odd), this means that $x^3$ has a factor with odd power which means that $x^3$ is not square. 
This contradicts with the argument's premise and therefore the initial conclusion is true.

Comment: $x$ is an element of a finite field, not an integer.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Bill. My answer seems to be useful only for integers.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth highlighting the underlying idea from an *additive* perspective.

$$\begin{align}  x^{\large n+1}\! = y^{\large n }\!\! &\overset{\Large (\ \ )/x^{\Large n}\!\!\!\!}\iff x = (y/x)^{\large n}\ \ \ \ \ \, \text{OP is case }\ n=2\\[.3em]
(n\!+\!1) x = n y \!\!&\ \iff x =  n(y\!-\!x)\ \ \ \ \text{in additive form}\\[.3em]
n\,\mid\, (n\!+\!1)x\!\! &\ \iff n\,\mid\, x\qquad\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \text{in divisibility form}\\[.3em]
\bmod n\!:\,\ 0\equiv (n\!+\!1)x\!\! &\ \iff 0\equiv x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{in congruence form}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Probably everyone can *immediately* see at least one of the last three, but sometimes we miss the first, because our *additive* intuition is often stronger than our *multiplicative* intuition (but compare my most [popular post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6250/242)).  To work around that it often helps to first translate multiplicative statements into additive form to spark intuition.