# Is the field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ a countable infinity or uncountable infinity?

Tags: field-theory, set-theory, extension-field

In looking at other questions/answers here on MSE, $[\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is infinite, but they didn't specify whether it was a countable infinity or uncountable infinity. I would guess uncountable since even a union of countably infinite many copies of a countable set like $\mathbb{Q}$ is still countably infinite, and the irrationals $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ are uncountable, but I'm not sure if a set-theoretic argument like that would transfer over to a statement about field extensions. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb), the dimension must be $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets) are explicit examples of continuum-sized $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you.