# Proving $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$ using induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, induction

I am aware of the standard proofs using a cardinality argument or using the fact that there infinitely many prime numbers (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb) post for instance). Using induction looked promising at first, but unfortunately I got stuck. What I am trying to prove is the following:

> There exist no numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \mathbb{R}$.

Assume the contrary to (hopefully) obtain contradictions:

For the base case $n=1$ we show that $\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1) = \mathbb{R}$ is impossible. If $x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, we get that $\sqrt{2} \notin \text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1)$, which is a contradiction. If $x_1 \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}$, we get that $1 \notin \text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1)$, since we would have a linear combination $1=\lambda_1x_1$, and the LHS is rational, whereas the RHS is not, contradiction.

For the induction hypothesis, assume that we have proven that $\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \mathbb{R}$ is impossible for any $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}) = \mathbb{R}$ is impossible.

Again, I assumed the contrary: For any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n+1}$ such that $y=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\lambda_ix_i$. This is equivalent to
$$
\lambda_1x_1+\ldots+\lambda_nx_n = y-\lambda_{n+1}x_{n+1}. \tag1
$$
It seemed like it would be helpful to have a term on the LHS that is not dependent on $x_{n+1}$ anymore. I thought about setting $y=0$, to obtain
$$
\lambda_1x_1+\ldots+\lambda_nx_n =-\lambda_{n+1}x_{n+1},
$$
but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

**My questions**:

1. Is a proof of this theorem by induction possible in the first place?
2. If yes, how can I apply the induction hypothesis to equation $(1)$?

Comment: The null vector belongs to the span of *any* subset $S$ of a vector space: just take $s\in S$ and use the fact that $0=0\times s$.

Comment: $0$ will be in every span of the set. In your case $\sqrt 2 x_1$ will not be in the span of $\{x_1\}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right, thank you for pointing that out! I think I fixed it now.

Comment: I do not think that pure induction will be successful. We only know that arbitary $n$ real numbers don't do the job (induction hypothesis). But there is no limit for this $n$. Without any additional argument, we probably won't be able to classify the "missing real numbers" to show that an additional real number cannot "fill the gap".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Peter. I had a hunch it wouldn't work using induction.