# Is this proof about why the vector space of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite-dimensional correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The problem says that

> Let $V$ be the set of real numbers. Regard $V$ as a vector space over the field of rational numbers, with the usual operations. Prove that this vector space is not finite-dimensional.

In my proof I use this Corollary:

"Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $n=\dim( V)$. Then any subset of $V$ which contains more than $n$ vectors is linearly dependent."

So, my proof goes like this:

"Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and let $n=\dim(V)$. Notice that the set $\left \{ \sqrt[m]{2}:m\geq  n,m\in \mathbb{N}  \right \}$ have more than $n$ vectors and is an independent set which is a contradiction by the lemma above, thus $V$ is not a finite-dimensional vector space. "

I was looking for another proofs on google but I could not find something like this, so is this proof correct? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not convinced. How do you know this set is independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You really couldn't find another proof of this on the internet?

Comment: @William in this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6517 they proved some similar

Comment: @DionelJaime No, my bad. I was trying to say that I could not find a proof using this corollary.

Comment: In that thread they show that the set of all $1/(2^n)$th roots of $2$ are independent. That's not what you're claiming. Hint: can you show that $2^{1/6}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/2}]$, and thereby conclude your claim is hopeless?

Comment: @William You are correct that the OP has failed to prove what they claim. You are also correct that $2^{1/6}\in\Bbb{Q}[2^{1/3},2^{1/2}]$. But that does not make the set $\{2^{1/2}, 2^{1/3},2^{1/6}\}$ linearly dependent. It actually is independent (over $\Bbb{Q}$). The minimal polynomial of $2^{1/6}$ is $x^6-2$, and therefore the set $2^{k/6}$, $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$, is linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @jyrki lahtonen right you are! That's my bad on the claim, I made an arithmetic error on a napkin.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you so much for your comment, but why I failed to prove the problem? I will appreciate so much your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof. Suppose $\mathbb R$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$ vector space, with basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. But $span\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\cong\mathbb Q^n$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ while $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is sufficient for the question that was asked once you show that those vectors are independent.  It could well be that you have already shown that, perhaps as a lead-in for this question. As Kenta S has shown, you can prove more, that the dimension is $\mathfrak c$, but you were not asked for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your coment a lot

Comment: Why is a comment posted as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linear algebra lemma in the following way. Suppose  that this vector space is of dimension $n$. Take any real number $\alpha$. Then the powers $1, \alpha,...,\alpha^n$ are linearly dependent (as in the lemma). Then for some $k\le n$ we have that $\alpha^k$ is a linear combination of $1,...,\alpha^{k-1}$ with rational coefficients. Hence $\alpha^k=a_0\cdot 1+...+a_{k-1}\alpha^{k-1}$, so $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^k-a_{k-1}x^{k-1}-...-a_0$, hence $\alpha$ is algebraic. But $\Bbb R$ contains transcendental numbers (say, $\pi$), a contradiction.

Comment: This is so nice!, thank you so much for you answer.